# Node-Red can't register AngularJS controller

Tags: angularjs, controller, dashboard, node-red

I want to build a user-interface with Node-Red, Node-Red-Dashboard and AngularJS.
I tried to use Dashboard's template-node with some AngularJS but it always fails to registering my controller and I just can't find the problem.

I finally just copied some simple example code to rule out any mistakes but still get the same error.

That's the code I copied in to the template-node:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl"> 
  First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
  Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
  Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>

<script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
  });
</script>
```

That is the error I get in the console:

```
app.min.js:140 Error: [$controller:ctrlreg] 
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.11/$controller/ctrlreg?p0=myCtrl
  at app.min.js:27
  at app.min.js:112
  at ba (app.min.js:95)
  at n (app.min.js:86)
  at g (app.min.js:80)
  at app.min.js:80
  at app.min.js:565
  at m.$digest (app.min.js:165)
  at m.$apply (app.min.js:168)
  at app.min.js:181
```

Comment: code looks good, check if you have added angularjs reference

Comment: When I add the angularjs reference, the code is still failing and I get a warning in the console: "WARNING: Tried to load AngularJS more than once." so I assume the the reference is added automatically by the template-node. I tried different node-red-dashboard examples I found on the internet, they all are failing. Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 2):

I think I've fireguard it out. You can't to register a controller, but you don't have to.

The code like this works fine:

```
<div>
  First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
  Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
  Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
</div>

<script>
  (function(scope) {
    scope.firstName= "John";
    scope.lastName= "Doe";
   })(scope)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="space-between">
 <p>The number is</p>
 <p ng-style="{color: (msg.payload || 0) % 2 === 0 ? 'green' : 'red'}">
  {{(msg.payload || 0) % 2 === 0 ? 'even' : 'odd'}}
 </p>
</div>
```

Will display if the number received as **msg.payload** is even or odd. It will also change the color of the text to green if the number is even or red if odd.
The next example shows how to set a unique id for your template, pick up the default theme colour, and watch for any incoming message.

```
 <div id="{{'my_'+$id}}" style="{{'color:'+theme.base_color}}">Some text</div>
<script>
console.log("ID",scope.$id);
console.log("THEME",scope.theme);
(function(scope) {
scope.$watch('msg', function(msg) {
 if (msg) {
   // Do something when msg arrives
   $("#my_"+scope.$id).html(msg.payload);
 }
});
})(scope);
</script>
```

Templates made in this way can be copied and remain independent of each other.

**Sending a message:**

```
<script>
  var value = "hello world";
 // or overwrite value in your callback function ...
 this.scope.action = function() { return value; }
</script>
<md-button ng-click="send({payload:action()})">
     Click me to send a hello world
</md-button>
```

Will display a button that when clicked will send a message with the payload 'Hello world'.
**Using msg.template**:
You can also define the template content via **msg.template**, so you can use external files for example.
Template will be reloaded on input if it has changed.
Code written in the Template field will be ignored when **msg.template** is present.